# Android Studio using 100% CPU on an i7 processor for project Rebuild

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My Windows 7 machine has a quad core i7 processor.  When I Rebuild my project, it takes on average 25 seconds.  And when I launch the app, it takes on average 36 seconds (before the app is uploaded to the device).

I have 588 files in my project's /src folder, which includes all of my java and xml code.  I've got two .so libs each 5MB and 7 jars in my /libs folder.

See my attached screenshot.  As you can see my CPU is maxed out at 100% the entire time.  My iTunes music pauses, and I get a "Poor Performance" pop-up in the lower right hand corner of my windows taskbar.  That's how bad it is.

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.1.1

Most of the time is spent during the preDex and dex operations.

Here's what I've tried so far (separately, I haven't tried them all together):

1. adding gradle.properties -> "org.gradle.daemon=true"
2. Power Saving
3. Mode Invalidate Caches /
4. Restart Global Gradle Setings -> Offline
5. work Compiler -> Make project automatically

Nothing has worked yet.  I can't imagine that this is a common problem, am I right?  Am I being too imaptient because this really is that much slower than Eclipse?

I guess my questions are:

1. Could this be due to the size of my jars or so files?
2. I tookover a project that had many nested views in XML files. Could this be causing a problem?

I'm really reaching for straws so if anyone has any information, esepecially why the dex operation is taking up so much CPU, that would be awesome.

I guess it goes without saying that this is happening if I edit an XML file, do a rebuild, and then launch the app.  If there's nothing to clean and rebuild... 
when I just do a Make Project... the average build time is 3 seconds.

[image]

Comment: Yes. Why is a development environment compiling and building a 588 file project taking 38 seconds and using 100% CPU on my i7 quad core processor.

Comment: How long does it take if you run the build from the CLI?

Comment: In Android Studio building a project takes a lot longer than it used to in Eclipse. Which is very unfortunate. Going back to Eclipse is not an option because the Eclipse ADT plugin and ant don't support multidex so you can't use the google play library.

Comment: 'gradlew.bat clean' followed by 'gradlew.bat assembleDebug' equals 5 seconds + 47 seconds

Comment: Blimey.  I just had the same issue, after downloading the latest Java JDK and Android Studio, and getting Android Studio to generate my first app based on a "Blank Activity".   It creates it, then uses up 100% CPU for 2-3 minutes doing "indexing".   I haven't even written a line of code yet, and the environment is at a standstill !!

Comment: For those still interested.. looks like Android Studio 2.0 has some serious improvements to build and deploy time!

Comment: @Lou Morda, they just added quick build to monkey patch the slowness. Even them can't seem to figure out how to fix it. Android Studio is crap and will always will be. It is very counter productive to work on this IDE. It took me 10 minutes to build. It is very annoying. But we have no choice but to bear it.

Answer (score 8):

Here are the three improvements I was able to make:

I was preDexing my JARs every time I built the project, so I found this solution:

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

I was using the entire Google Play Services library:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

When all I needed was Google Cloud Messenger:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

In Eclipse, I would always do a Rebuild and then launch app with the play button.  In Android Studio, now I am just doing a Clean and then launch app with the play button. Also the Run button in Android Studio does NOT work every time right after the Clean.  This was causing what seemed to be delays because nothing was happening. So now I leave the Gradle Console open to make sure that the run button is working, and when it doesn't I just hit it a second time.

What I used to have:

```
Rebuild: 26 seconds
Launch:  36 seconds
Install: 15 seconds
```

and now:

```
Clean:    8 seconds
Launch:  22 seconds
Install: 15 seconds
```

which is a major improvement! Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Your examples for Google Play Services and Google Cloud Messenger are identical...

Comment: Where do you put dexOptions

Answer (score 6):

As stated on the [tracker page for this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66696), the team has identified this as the problem:

> --parallel-threads only applies to project parallelization.
>
> For android tasks that are running in parallel, we always create as
>   many threads as possible

From the page, it seems that they target release 1.3 to address this (see comment #13 there).

In the meantime, what has helped me to cope on Windows 7 is to set the CPU affinity for the Android Studio process (and its child processes) to spare at least one of the cores (as suggested by comment #9 on the page).

There are many ways to do this, but you might want to try the [top-voted answer on this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/349591/how-can-i-set-the-default-affinity-for-any-process-in-windows) (which suggested to use [Process Lasso](http://bitsum.com/prolasso.php)) that appears to work well enough for me.

Comment: This issue has been standing on for 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to optimizations specific to Gradle (see below), I recommend that you try **disabling anti-virus** protection for your Gradle caches directory and your Android Studio project directory. For me, this reduces my build times by roughly 50%. Excluding those same directories from Windows Search indexing can also help.

Gradle optimizations I use, in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties.

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx6144m <-- Tweak this based on available RAM
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
kotlin.incremental=true
```

Note that enabling caching means you sometimes have to explicitly clear your caches when switching branches. I run this script when I run into puzzling build issues.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Clean Android cache
./gradlew cleanBuildCache

# Clean Gradle cache, prompting for each directory
find ~/.gradle/caches -maxdepth 1 -name build-cache* -print -exec rm -rfI {} \;

# Clean Project
./gradlew clean

# Stop Gradle Daemon
./gradlew --stop
```

Answer (score -2):

To be honest, Android Studio is hands down better than Eclipse because of the UI designer.  The downside is that it uses gradle instead of Ant.  Gradle is also better but slower - especially on Windows.  It runs much better on Linux. If you haven't used Linux before, fear not.  Linux Mint is a stable OS that has a UI that is similar to Windows. You'll be right at home in no time. It consumes fewer resources so that leaves more processing power for the gradle build. Make the switch. You'll never go back.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of trying that, but I'm not sure why gradle would use less CPU on Linux?  The problem is my CPU is going from about 5% to 100% for 30 seconds, and the only change is that I'm running a gradle build

Comment: Yea, it makes Android development almost unbearable. So far I haven't seen any solve for it.  There's one feature called "parallelism" that increase performance but it's still experimental.  Also, if you have sub projects you can save yourself some compile time by packaging those up as jar files instead. It just means less work for the compiler.

Comment: This answer does not address the issue : changing the OS for a performance issue in a software is not a realistic answer. Other answer shows that the problem is inside the software itself. In addition, in the next answer in "tracker page for this issue", some people report same issue on Linux.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm compiling my projects in record time.  Dell 4800 Precision Workstation, Linux Mint 17.3, 32 GB RAM, Dual Samsung 840EVO SSDs in Raid 0.

Comment: Better UI Designer? I beg to disagree, its the same with Eclipse, its not very good. I only use it to check if my layout is correct before I press the button since it took me 10minutes to build to see my recent changes. That's the only use for me.

Comment: Sure. Both of the designers could be better but the designer in Android Studio is better than the one in Eclipse.  Still, I end up hand coding layouts in sublime anyway.  Takes a bit longer but you get more control.

Comment: @itsben you are using crazily expensive and powerful hardware, of course you are not suffering that much for the issue. Your machine covers the slowness. Actually the same problem happens on Linux as well (Ubuntu, for instance).

Comment: Yes @AndreaLazzarotto, you are correct.  The M4800 is one of the most powerful mobile workstations you can buy.  It's not as cute or as light weight as other laptops but scores over 7000 on linux bench.  They aren't as expensive as they used to be.  You can grab a refurbished one on Ebay for less than a Macbook Pro. Just know the fastest processors, ram and ssds. Put them all together and you've got a powerhouse that will tackle anything.  I forgot to mention I have 32 GB of DDR3 ram as well.

Comment: So for anyone else that comes along on this thread and gets pissed off because Android projects don't compile quickly on their machine, look at your machine first.  To date, besides parallelism there is no way to speed up a gradle build.  You can organize your project to reduce the amount of compiling necessary but still it's slower than ANT.  Compiling on Windows is going to be slower because of disk fragmentation and the amount of resources the OS consumes.  If you want more speed from the same hardware, go Linux.

Comment: Android Studio Sucks, its so damn heavy, does so much shit in the background and makes everything look so god damn important. Stupid development. Unfortunately a necessary evil. I miss the eclipse days.

Comment: I stay out of the IDEs if at all possible.  Sublime Text does the code and layout edits.  You can compile everything at the terminal with gradle.